# CPAN fails to install DateTime module

Tags: perl, cpan, time

I tried to install the Perl DateTime module by running "cpan" and typing "install DateTime" at the prompt.  After a lot of processing and printing I got this message:

```
Compilation failed in require at (eval 907) line 3.
# Looks like your test died before it could output anything.
t/41cldr_format.........dubious                                              
        Test returned status 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
DIED. FAILED tests 1-101
        Failed 101/101 tests, 0.00% okay
t/42duration_class......ok                                                   
t/pod-coverage..........skipped
        all skipped: Test::Pod::Coverage 1.08 required for testing POD coverage
t/pod...................skipped
        all skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
Failed Test          Stat Wstat Total Fail  Failed  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/07compare.t         255 65280    26   18  69.23%  18-26
t/17set_return.t      255 65280     7   12 171.43%  2-7
t/19leap_second.t     255 65280   172  302 175.58%  22-172
t/23storable.t        255 65280    21   42 200.00%  1-21
t/24from_object.t     255 65280    10    8  80.00%  7-10
t/30future_tz.t       255 65280     5   10 200.00%  1-5
t/34set_tz.t          255 65280     8   16 200.00%  1-8
t/36invalid_local.t   255 65280     4    5 125.00%  1-4
t/37local-add.t       255 65280    26   52 200.00%  1-26
t/38local-subtract.t  255 65280   127  254 200.00%  1-127
t/41cldr_format.t     255 65280   101  202 200.00%  1-101
3 tests and 9 subtests skipped.
Failed 11/44 test scripts, 75.00% okay. 462/3296 subtests failed, 85.98% okay.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  DROLSKY/DateTime-0.50.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports DROLSKY/DateTime-0.50.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 DROLSKY/DateTime-0.50.tar.gz                 : make_test NO
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I am running Fedora.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What OS / Distro are you using?  It is generally easier to install these modules from a package because that will get the dependencies too.  In Ubuntu you would just:

```
sudo apt-get install libdatetime-perl
```

Comment: That worked, although I used yum since I'm on Fedora.

Comment: It also turns out that the package I was looking for was TimeDate, not DateTime...

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I like CPAN for the less popular modules, like ones I made:-), but common ones with lots of dependencies I try to get them from the repositories.  I have never had any trouble with mixing the two.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I also failed to install the "DateTime" module by using "cpanm" on Fedora 14; I do want to use this module though, instead of your "TimeDate".

Turn into root, and
"**yum install perl-DateTime.i686**"

This gets the work done@_@